# Не копируется каталог при выполнении команды

Tags: linux

Я хочу скопировать каталог. Структура моего проекта такова.

```
project
    dist
        ...
    src
        ...
    package.json
    templates
        template.html
        ...
    ...
```

Я хочу скопировать каталог `templates` со всеми файлами в папку `dist`.

Посмотрев как работает команда `cp` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp я решил сделать скрипт.

```
"scripts": {
    "copy-templates": "cp -r ./templates ./dist",
    ...
```

При выполнении команды `npm run copy-templates` я получаю ошибку.

> cp: невозможно перезаписать поверх файла './dist/templates', не являющегося каталогом, каталог './templates'

Из-за чего я не могу скопировать катало?

Comment: сообщение об ошибке говорит о том, что в папке dist уже есть что то с именем templates и это не каталог (скорее всего это файл)

Comment: @Mike да, так и было(

Comment: Если ваш скрипт, на npm, будет запущен пользователем не имеющим прав на запись в жестко указанном пути - будет та же ошибка.